# Can you explain the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I have asked for money from Jagan next time if he comes.

I am bit confused, whether it is completed in past or it will be in future.

Answer (score 6):

It is structurally awkward, but indicates that Jagan will contribute the next time the group meets, if he is able to make an appearance.

I would further conclude that if he is unable to make the next meeting, that he and his contribution will appear at the meeting after that.

> I am bit confused, whether it is completed in past or it will be in
>   future.

The asking happened in the past.  The actual transfer of money will happen in the future, *if and when* Jagan can attend.

Comment: Please revert the edit if you think I've got it wrong. I think you're right re the the default assumption. Even if Jagan doesn't/can't attend the *next* meeting, he'll be expected to pay if/when he attends a *subsequent* meeting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I appreciate your edit. Thanks!

Comment: Your English in general (and particularly, your knowledge of *idiomatic* usages) is so good it seems clear to me you must be a *very* competent AmE speaker. And there are even uncertainties over exactly how *bring* is used in ***BrE*** (especially between mainland and N. Irish). But something about your original didn't *quite* sit well with me. I kinda wanted to just tack on the word ***in***, but I figured that might be a US/UK divide. Anyway, I'm happy if you're happy - and if nothing else, your comment pinged me to remind me I forgot to actually click on the upvote button!